# Restoring MySQL Master-Master Replication

Tags: mysql, replication, mysql-5.6, multi-master

I am trying to restore Master-Master MySQL 5.6 servers. The replication failed between DB1=>DB2 and so DB2 went out of sync.

GTIDs are enabled.

I have done an export and import from DB1 to DB2 and restarted the slave, all looks good, changes are being replicated.

I am unsure however to get DB1 slaved to DB2 again, with the slave running no changes are replicated. I am thinking I need to do `reset master` on one or both and restart the replication, does any one know the correct way to do this?

Comment: have you checked error log is there anything there?